# Scrambled screen

Tags: boot

Trying to install ubuntu 14 from USB. On first attempt, there was error. Was asked to restart.
On restart, selecting either of the options: 1. Try without installing, 2. Install Ubuntu, 3. Check for disk errors,.. Getting black and white scrambled screen ( as in top quarter of screen having haphazard white inks with rest of black screen)
Tried rebooting and same issue persist.
Could this indicate hard disk errors?

There was earlier issue of blue screen of death leading to inability to load windows 8.

Comment: No. Scrambled screen = video card. Try booting with "nomodeset" from the grub prompt.